# sshd_config failure, is there a fallback?

Tags: ssh, sshd

So.. I decided to act like a complete moron and changed the Port to 81234 (which i now realize is higher than 65535), thus I can not login to my SSH anymore.

Is there any kind of fallback or default it reverts to in case of epic failure?

Comment: Do you have an FTP access to this server?

Comment: Not SFTP, but true FTP

Comment: Sorry for the late response, Daniel. No, FTP is evil, I only use SFTP.

Comment: Any luck so far?

Comment: Yeah it has been fixed, but I can't mark my answer as the solution

Comment: Ah.  I can fix that...

Comment: See the bottom of the page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the OP:

To sum up the answers and comments: there is no fallback. Screwing up the config means you're screwed.

In the mean time, the VPS provider has been able to reset my port, so this issue is resolved :D

Answer (score 1):

There is no fallback. If you screw up `sshd` settings and close your only connection that did this change after `sshd` restart (basically turning off the old config and letting the new fail), there is no way to connect again using ssh since it is in failed state.

The only way is to use local access or console (some VPS provide remote console).

Comment: Unfortunately, this particular VPS provider doesn't :D But my support ticket is being addressed at this moment, so I hope they can fix stuff using the console.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried port 15698? That would 81234 as a short overflowed. Here's some sample c-code that demonstrates the overflow:

```
int main(){

  unsigned short p = 81234;

  printf("port: %hu\n",p);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, sadly it didn't work :(

Comment: I just did a simple test on my VM, and with that setting, ssh starts but there is no listening port indicated in netstat output ---- I think you may be hosed. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for testing it! I think I just found something that could use a fix in the ssh server :D

Answer (score 0):

To sum up the answers and comments: there is no fallback. Screwing up the config means you're screwed.

In the mean time, the VPS provider has been able to reset my port, so this issue is resolved :D